# using Observable in Angular 10 properly, value never changes

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I'm trying to understand how to use Observables In Angular 10 for loading indicators and for data change in some graphql functions that I have.. and I'm missing basic implementation that I don't understand.

lets take a boolean value for loading indicator as an example.

so in my component class I have this:

```
private readonly loading = new Subject<boolean>();
get loading$(): Observable<boolean> {
 return this.loading;
}
```

in the template html file I have this:

```
{{(this.loading$ | async) ? 'true' : 'false'}}
```

the problem is that it's alway prints `false`

in `ngOnInit()` function I added `this.loading.next(true);` but the html template still prints `false`.

what am I missing ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about observables, it's about Angular component life cycle.

> in ngOnInit() function I added this.loading.next(true); but the html template still prints false.

That's too early - the observable emits once, *before* the template is rendered, effectively before anyone's listening to the stream. But the same code will work if put in `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xefd3z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I would not use a setter. I would just do something like:

```
loading$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

ngOnInit() {
   this.loading$.next(true)
   // setTimeout should be cleared but this is just to show toggling works
   setTimeout(() => {this.loading$.next(false)}, 2000)
}
```

Explanation: A behaviorSubject has an initial value (false). The behaviorSubject is an Observable so you can print it with the async pipe in your template.
In ngOnInit the behaviorSubject gets a next of true, and after the timeout a next of false, just to showcase stream value changes